# Detect Label in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple Threejs code where I am testing the click event with Raycaster. I used the BOX geometry to create three cubes. Using CSS2DRenderer.js, I  have added a label above one of the cubes. I want to click on the label to bring up a popup with some information. I see that the cubes are detected when I click, but the label is not. Is the raycaster limited to meshes? If that's the case, how do I detect my label on click? You can find the click event code below:

```
window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    raycaster.setFromCamera(clickMouse, camera);
    const found = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    console.log(found);
});
```

Comment: `const found = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true)`

Comment: With latest `three.js` releases, the `recursive` parameter of `intersectObjects()` is true by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `Raycaster` for detecting 3D objects like meshes, point clouds or lines. For labels rendered via `CSS2DRenderer`, you can just add a `pointerdown` event listener to the respective label DOM element.